# integral $\int(4x+9)\ln x\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have trouble calculating this integral. I include my calculations for easier troubleshooting.

$$\int(4x+9)\ln x\,dx = 4\int x \ln x \,dx + 9\int x \ln x\,dx = 4(x \ln x - x)+9(x \ln x - x)$$

Comment: The second integrand (with the coefficient $9$) should be just $\ln x$, not $x\ln x$. You are also integrating $x\ln x$ incorrectly (try by parts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the second term, as mentioned in a comment. Regarding the first term, integration by parts gives
$$
\int x \ln x dx = \frac12 x^2 \ln x-\int \frac 12 x^2 \cdot \frac 1x dx = \frac 12 x^2 \ln x - \frac 14 x^2 + C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

> using integration by parts

**In the general case**
$$\int\;(ax＋b)\ln(x)dx＝(\frac {ax^2}{2}＋bx)\ln(x)－\int\;(\frac {ax^2}{2}＋bx)×\frac {1}{x}\;dx\\~\\＝(\frac {ax^2}{2}＋bx)\ln(x)－\int(\frac {ax}{2}＋b)\;dx＝(\frac {ax^2}{2}＋bx)\ln(x)－(\frac {ax^2}{4}＋bx)\\~\\＝\frac {ax^2}{2}(\ln(x)－\textstyle\frac {1}{2}))＋bx(\ln(x)－\textstyle\frac {1}{2})-\frac {bx}{2}\\~\\＝(\ln(x)－\textstyle\frac {1}{2}))(\frac {ax^2}{2}＋bx)－\frac {bx}{2}\\~\\$$

**In your example we have a =4 and b=9**
So :
$$\int\;(4x＋9)\ln(x)dx＝(\ln(x)－\textstyle\frac {1}{2})(\frac {4x^2}{2}＋9x)－\frac {9x}{2}＝(\ln(x)－\textstyle\frac {1}{2})(2x^2＋9x)－\frac {9x}{2}$$